# Scheme procedure that tests a functional relation and a one-to-one relationship

Tags: scheme, racket, one-to-one

A relation R between sets A and B is called functional if for any element a in set A there is a unique element b in set B such that pair (a b) is in set R.

```
(functional '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6) '((1 4) (2 4) (3 5))
; ==> #t
(functional '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6) '((1 4) (1 6) (2 5) (3 5))
; ==> #f
```

For one-to-one

```
(one-to-one '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6 7) '((1 4) (2 6) (3 7))
; ==> #t
(one-to-one '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6 7) '((1 4) (2 4) (3 7))
; ==> #f
```

here is my code for one-to-one

```
(define one-to-one
  (lambda (a b r)
    (cond
      ((null? r)
       #t)
      ((one-to-one-helper (first r) (rest r))
       #f)
      (else
       (one-to-one a b (rest r))))))

(define one-to-one-helper
  (lambda (pair set)
    (cond
      ((null? set)
       #f)
      ((eq? (rest pair) (rest (first set)))
       #t)
      (else
       (one-to-one-helper pair (rest set))))))
```

my second tester should return false but it is returning true

Answer (score 0):

The reason why second test case results in false is because your `one-to-one-helper` function uses `eq?` when testing equality. To illustrate:

```
> (eq? '(4) '(4))
#f
> (eqv? '(4) '(4))
#f
> (equal? '(4) '(4))
#t
```

whereas,

```
> (eq? 4 4)
#t
> (eqv? 4 4)
#t
> (equal? 4 4)
#t
```

Hence, to fix your problem, you can either change to `equal?`:

```
((equal? (rest pair) (rest (first set)))
```

or do your comparison on atomic elements instead:

```
((eq? (cadr pair) (cadar set))
```

Here is a sample implementation of an injective (one to one) predicate function, using `equal?` for comparison:

```
(define (injective? mapping)
  (define (one-to-one? pair mapping)
    (or (null? mapping)
        (and (not (equal? (cadr pair) (cadar mapping)))
             (one-to-one? (car mapping) (cdr mapping)))))
  (or (null? mapping)
      (and (one-to-one? (car mapping) (cdr mapping))
           (injective? (cdr mapping)))))
```

For example,

```
> (injective? '((1 4) (2 6) (3 7)))
#t
> (injective? '((1 4) (2 4) (3 7)))
#f
```